# Delete objects from datasources in selectable datatable

Tags: flutter, dart

i am beginner in FLutter and i have created an app that get a list of players from an api and then filters the list of players by their position , everything is working perfect , except one little thing , every time when i select a player and add it to selectedPlayers List and then if i click again and this player is still selected it must not appear in the list again until i unselect this player then player must appear again ,
My problem is that the players that are selected are not deleting in the list and i have a problem of duplicate , i am trying to find a solution for this problem

My Playerr model class:

```
class Playerr {

  int _playerID;
  String _firstName;
  String _lastName;
  String _position;
  String _team;
  double _price = 5;
  String rating;
  int _appearances = 0;
  int _goals = 0;
  int _assists = 0;
  int _cleanSheets = 0;
  int _redCards = 0;
  int _yellowCards = 0;
  String _image;

  Playerr(this._playerID, this._firstName, this._lastName, this._position,
      this._team,
      this.rating, this._appearances, this._goals, this._assists,
      this._cleanSheets, this._redCards,
      this._yellowCards) {

    if (_position == ("Goalkeeper")) {
      this._image = "assets/goal.png";
    } else {
      this._image = "assets/shirt" + team.toString() + ".png";
    }

    if(rating == null){
      rating = "5.000000";
      _price = 3;
    }else if((double.parse(rating) >= 6.0) && (double.parse(rating) < 7.0)){
    _price = 6;
    }else if((double.parse(rating) >= 7.0) && (double.parse(rating) < 8.0)){
      _price = 15;
    }else if(double.parse(rating) >= 8.0){
      _price = 30;
    }
    if(appearances == null){
      appearances = 0;
    }

    if(redCards == null){
      redCards = 0;
    }

    if(yellowCards == null){
      yellowCards = 0;
    }

    if(price == null){
      price = 0;
    }

    if(goals == null){
      goals = 0;
    }else if(goals>=5 && goals < 10){
      price+=5;
    }else if(goals>=10 && goals <20){
      price+=10;
    }else if(goals>=20){
      price+=20;
    }
    if(assists == null){
      assists = 0;
    }else if(assists >= 5 && assists <10){
      price+=5;
    }else if(assists >= 10 && assists <20){
      price+=10;
    }else if(assists >= 10){
      price+=20;
    }

    if(cleanSheets == null){
      cleanSheets = 0;
    }else if(cleanSheets >= 30){
      price+=15;
    }

  }

  factory Playerr.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Playerr(int.parse(json['player']['id']), json['player']['firstname'], json['player']['lastname'],
     json['statistics'][0]['games']['position'],
     json['statistics'][0]['team']['name'],
        json['statistics'][0]['games']['rating'],
        int.parse(json['statistics'][0]['games']['appearances']),
        int.parse(json['statistics'][0]['goals']['total']),
         int.parse(json['statistics'][0]['goals']['assists']), int.parse(json['statistics'][0]['goals']['saves']),
        int.parse(json['statistics'][0]['cards']['yellow']), int.parse(json['statistics'][0]['cards']['red']));
  }

  Playerr.empty() {
    this.image = "assets/shirt_blank.png";
    this.firstName = "firstname";
    this.lastName = "lastname";
  }

  String get image => _image;

  set image(String value) {
    _image = value;
  }

 

  int get yellowCards => _yellowCards;

  set yellowCards(int value) {
    _yellowCards = value;
  }

  int get redCards => _redCards;

  set redCards(int value) {
    _redCards = value;
  }

  int get cleanSheets => _cleanSheets;

  set cleanSheets(int value) {
    _cleanSheets = value;
  }

  int get assists => _assists;

  set assists(int value) {
    _assists = value;
  }

  int get goals => _goals;

  set goals(int value) {
    _goals = value;
  }

  
  int get appearances => _appearances;

  set appearances(int value) {
    _appearances = value;
  }
  

  
  double get price => _price;

  set price(double value) {
    _price = value;
  }


  String get team => _team;

  set team(String value) {
    _team = value;
  }

  String get position => _position;

  set position(String value) {
    _position = value;
  }

  String get lastName => _lastName;

  set lastName(String value) {
    _lastName = value;
  }

  String get firstName => _firstName;

  set firstName(String value) {
    _firstName = value;
  }

  int get playerID => _playerID;

  set playerID(int value) {
    _playerID = value;
  }

  String get fullName => _firstName + " " + _lastName;
}
```

Here screen captures that shows what i did

[image]

[image]

afer i selected the first player on the list

i go to choose another player and i still find him not deleted ,

[image]

which mean i have duplicate players , i need to make sure that i do not have any copy of any player when he is selected , and i need also to make sure that after the player is deleted that he will come back to the list when he is replaced and not in selectedPlayers anymore ,

Here the full code of the api and the selection and filter of players:

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:footyappp/Fantazyy/Playerrs.dart';
import 'package:footyappp/Fantazyy/club_api.dart';
import 'package:footyappp/Fantazyy/create_team_view.dart';
import 'package:footyappp/Fantazyy/player%20copy.dart';
import 'package:footyappp/Fantazyy/player_lab.dart';
import 'package:footyappp/Key/Key.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class PlayersCreationDetailsView extends StatefulWidget {

  final List<Playerr> selectedPlayers;
  final int playerIndex;

  const PlayersCreationDetailsView ({
    Key key,
    @required this.selectedPlayers,
    @required this.playerIndex
  })  : super(key: key);

  @override
  _PlayersCreationDetailsViewState createState() => _PlayersCreationDetailsViewState();
}


class _PlayersCreationDetailsViewState extends State<PlayersCreationDetailsView> {
  bool _sortAsc = false;
  int _sortColumnIndex = 0;
  double _columnWidth  = 40.0;
  double _columnNameWidth  = 60.0;
  double _columnPosWidth  = 80.0;
  PlayersDataSource _playersDataSource;
  List<Playerr> _players = [];
  List<ClubApi> selectedClubs = [];
  List<int> clubIdentifiers = [];
  List<Playerrs> playersjson = [];
  List<Playerr> playersApi = [];
    List<dynamic> playerList ;
   List _table;


  int _rowsPerPage = 20;
   final String apiUrl =
      "https://v3.football.api-sports.io/players?season=2020&league=39";
  
  static const headers = {
    'x-rapidapi-host': "v3.football.api-sports.io",
    //Always make sure to check the api key and the limit of a request in a free api
    'x-rapidapi-key': "f6ebead51a2ade65b73948c623b1da95"
  };

  void _sort<T>(Comparable<T> getField(Playerr p), int columnIndex, bool ascending) {
    _playersDataSource._sort<T>(getField, ascending);
    setState(() {
      _sortColumnIndex = columnIndex;
      _sortAsc = ascending ;
    });
  }


  Future<void> getClubIds() async {
    http.Response response = await http.get(
        "https://v3.football.api-sports.io/teams?season=2020&league=39",
        headers: {'x-rapidapi-host': "v3.football.api-sports.io",
          'x-rapidapi-key': ApiKey.key});
    String body = response.body;
    var data = jsonDecode(body);
    List<dynamic> table = data['response'];

    setState(() {
      selectedClubs = table
          .map((dynamic item) => ClubApi.fromJson(item))
          .toList();

      for(var item in selectedClubs){
         clubIdentifiers.add(item.team.id);
      }

      for(var item in clubIdentifiers){
        print("club id"+item.toString());
        this.getPlayer(item);
      }

    });

  }


  Future<void> getPlayer(int id) async {
    http.Response response = await http.get(
      "https://v3.football.api-sports.io/players?season=2020&league=39&team=$id",
        headers: {'x-rapidapi-host': "v3.football.api-sports.io",
    'x-rapidapi-key': ApiKey.key});
    String body = response.body;
    var data = jsonDecode(body);
    List<dynamic> table = data['response'];

    setState(() {
      playersjson = table
          .map((dynamic item) => Playerrs.fromJson(item))
          .toList();

      for(var item in playersjson){
        String pos = item.statistics[0].games.position.toString().substring(8);
        playersApi.add(Playerr(item.player.id,item.player.firstname, item.player.lastname, pos,
            item.statistics[0].team.name,item.statistics[0].games.rating, item.statistics[0].games.appearences,item.statistics[0].goals.total,
            item.statistics[0].goals.assists,item.statistics[0].goals.conceded,
            item.statistics[0].cards.red, item.statistics[0].cards.yellow));
      }
      print(playersApi.length);
      // for(var item in playersApi){
      //   print("position"+item.position.toString());
      // print(item.position.contains("DEFENDER"));
      // }
      for(var item in playersApi){
        print("position"+item.position.toString());

      }
      if (widget.playerIndex < 2) {
        _players = playersApi.where((player) => player

            .position.contains("GOALKEEPER")).toList();
      } else if (widget.playerIndex < 7) {
        _players = playersApi.where((player) => player.position.contains("DEFENDER")).toList();
      } else if (widget.playerIndex < 12) {
        _players = playersApi.where((player) => player.position.contains("MIDFIELDER")).toList();
      } else {
        _players = playersApi.where((player) => player.position.contains("ATTACKER")).toList();
      }
      //filter out players who are already selected

        for (Playerr player in widget.selectedPlayers) {
          _players.remove(player);
        }
        _playersDataSource = PlayersDataSource(widget.playerIndex, widget.selectedPlayers, _players, context);

    });

  }

@override
  void initState() {
  super.initState();
  this.getClubIds();
    //filter out players by position

  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print(playersApi.length);

    return  playersApi.length == 0
        ? Container(
      color: Colors.white,
      child: Center(
        child: CircularProgressIndicator(
          valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(
            Color(0xFFe70066),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    )
        : WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () async => false,
      child: Scaffold(
        body: ListView(
          children: <Widget>[
            PaginatedDataTable(
              columnSpacing: 1.0,
              horizontalMargin: 1.0,
              availableRowsPerPage: [10,20,50],
              rowsPerPage: _rowsPerPage,
              onRowsPerPageChanged: (int value) { setState(() { _rowsPerPage = value; }); },
              sortColumnIndex: _sortColumnIndex,
              sortAscending: _sortAsc,
              header: Text("Players"),
              columns: <DataColumn>[
                new DataColumn(
                    label: new Container(width: _columnPosWidth , child: Text("First Name", softWrap: true,)),
                    numeric: true,
                    onSort: (int columnIndex, bool ascending) => _sort<String>((Playerr p) => p.firstName, columnIndex, ascending)
                ),
                new DataColumn(
                    label: new Container(width: _columnPosWidth , child: Text("Last Name", softWrap: true,)),
                    numeric: true,
                    onSort: (int columnIndex, bool ascending) => _sort<String>((Playerr p) => p.lastName, columnIndex, ascending)
                ),
                new DataColumn(
                    label: new Container(width: _columnPosWidth , child: Text("Position", softWrap: true,)),
                    numeric: true,
                    onSort: (int columnIndex, bool ascending) => _sort<String>((Playerr p) => p.position, columnIndex, ascending)
                ),
                  new DataColumn(
                    label: new Container(width: _columnPosWidth , child: new Text("Price")),
                    numeric: true,
                    onSort: (int columnIndex, bool ascending) => _sort<num>((Playerr p) => p.price, columnIndex, ascending)
                ),
                new DataColumn(
                    label: new Container(width: _columnPosWidth , child: Text("Rating", softWrap: true,)),
                    numeric: true,
                    onSort: (int columnIndex, bool ascending) => _sort<String>((Playerr p) => p.rating, columnIndex, ascending)
                ),
               /* new DataColumn(
                    label: new Container(width: _columnWidth , child: new Text("Position")),
                    numeric: true,
                    onSort: (int columnIndex, bool ascending) => _sort<String>((Playerr p) => p.position, columnIndex, ascending)
                ),*/
                new DataColumn(
                    label: new Container(width: _columnPosWidth , child: new Text("Team")),
                    numeric: true,
                    onSort: (int columnIndex, bool ascending) => _sort<String>((Playerr p) => p.team, columnIndex, ascending)
                ),
                
                new DataColumn(
                    label: new Container(width: _columnPosWidth , child: new Text("Apps")),
                    numeric: true,
                    onSort: (int columnIndex, bool ascending) => _sort<num>((Playerr p) => p.appearances, columnIndex, ascending)
                ),
              
               /* new DataColumn(
                    label: new Container(width: _columnWidth , child: new Text("Points")),
                    numeric: true,
                    onSort: (int columnIndex, bool ascending) => _sort<num>((Player p) => p.points, columnIndex, ascending)
                ),
                new DataColumn(
                    label: new Container(width: _columnWidth , child: new Text("Week Points")),
                    numeric: true,
                    onSort: (int columnIndex, bool ascending) => _sort<num>((Player p) => p.pointsWeek, columnIndex, ascending)
                ),*/
               
               /* new DataColumn(
                    label: new Container(width: _columnWidth , child: new Text("Sub Apps")),
                    numeric: true,
                    onSort: (int columnIndex, bool ascending) => _sort<num>((Player p) => p.subAppearances, columnIndex, ascending)
                ),*/
                new DataColumn(
                    label: new Container(width: _columnPosWidth , child: new Text("Goals")),
                    numeric: true,
                    onSort: (int columnIndex, bool ascending) => _sort<num>((Playerr p) => p.goals, columnIndex, ascending)
                ),
                new DataColumn(
                    label: new Container(width: _columnPosWidth , child: new Text("Assists")),
                    numeric: true,
                    onSort: (int columnIndex, bool ascending) => _sort<num>((Playerr p) => p.assists, columnIndex, ascending)
                ),
                
                new DataColumn(
                    label: new Container(width: _columnPosWidth , child: new Text("Clean")),
                    numeric: true,
                    onSort: (int columnIndex, bool ascending) => _sort<num>((Playerr p) => p.cleanSheets, columnIndex, ascending)
                ),
                new DataColumn(
                    label: new Container(width: _columnPosWidth , child: new Text("Yellows")),
                    numeric: true,
                    onSort: (int columnIndex, bool ascending) => _sort<num>((Playerr p) => p.yellowCards, columnIndex, ascending)
                ),
                new DataColumn(
                    label: new Container(width: _columnPosWidth , child: new Text("Reds")),
                    numeric: true,
                    onSort: (int columnIndex, bool ascending) => _sort<num>((Playerr p) => p.redCards, columnIndex, ascending)
                ),
               
              ],
              source: _playersDataSource,
            )
          ],
        )
      )
    );
  }
}

class PlayersDataSource extends DataTableSource {

  PlayersDataSource(this._playerIndex, this._selectedPlayers, this._players, this.context);

  int _playerIndex;
  List<Playerr> _players;
  List<Playerr> _selectedPlayers;

  int _selectedCount = 0;
  var context;
  double _columnWidth  = 40.0;
  double _columnNameWidth  = 60.0;
  double _columnPosWidth  = 80.0;

  void _sort<T>(Comparable<T> getField(Playerr p), bool ascending) {
    _players.sort((Playerr a, Playerr b) {
      if (!ascending) {
        final Playerr c = a;
        a = b;
        b = c;
      }
      final Comparable<T> aValue = getField(a);
      final Comparable<T> bValue = getField(b);
      return Comparable.compare(aValue, bValue);
    });
    notifyListeners();
  }

  DataCell getCell(String text) {
    return DataCell(Container(width: _columnPosWidth, child: Text(text, overflow: TextOverflow.fade, softWrap: false,)));
  }

  


  @override
  DataRow getRow(int index) {
    assert(index >= 0);
    if (index >= _players.length)
      return null;
    final Playerr player = _players[index];
    return DataRow.byIndex(
      onSelectChanged: (bool) {
        _players.removeAt(index);
        _selectedPlayers[_playerIndex] = player;
        Navigator.pushReplacement(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) {return CreateTeamView(players: _players, selectedPlayers: _selectedPlayers,);}));
      },
        index: index,
        cells: <DataCell>[
          getCell(player.firstName),
          getCell(player.lastName),
          getCell(player.position),
         getCell('${player.price}'),
          getCell('${player.rating}'),
         // getCell('${player.isFresher}'),
          getCell('${player.team}'),
          //getCell('${player.points}'),
         // getCell('${player.pointsWeek}'),
          getCell('${player.appearances}'),
         // getCell('${player.subAppearances}'),
          getCell('${player.goals}'),
          getCell('${player.assists}'),
          getCell('${player.cleanSheets}'),
         // getCell('${player.motms}'),
          getCell('${player.yellowCards}'),
          getCell('${player.redCards}'),
        //  getCell('${player.ownGoals}'),
        ]
    );
  }

  @override
  int get rowCount => _players.length;

  @override
  bool get isRowCountApproximate => false;

  @override
  int get selectedRowCount => _selectedCount;


}
```

I am really stuck and comfused , still the problem comfuses me,  the players are coming from api json and there is no duplicate at all , i am speaking here about the list of api must not show again a player that is already selected and pushed to selectedPlayers but it must show it again when the player is not in the list selectedPlayers anymore.
Any help will really so useful and so appreciated

Comment: Maybe you need to override [equality operator](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.12.0/dart-core/Object/operator_equals.html) at your Playerr class

Comment: how to do that exactly?

Comment: but i have a filter method here in the code , i will post my Playerr class

Comment: i posted my model class :)

Comment: do not forget that the players are coming from api json and there is no duplicate at all , i am speaking here about the list of api must not show again a player that is already selected and pushed to selectedPlayers but it must show it again when the player is not in the list selectedPlayers anymore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's assume that only the `_playerID` on your `Playerr` class is unique. So override these `operator ==` and `hashCode` like below :

```
class Playerr {
  int _playerID;
  
  // ...

  @override
  bool operator ==(Object other) =>
      identical(this, other) ||
      other is Playerr &&
          runtimeType == other.runtimeType &&
          _playerID == other._playerID;

  @override
  int get hashCode => _playerID.hashCode;
}
```

Then you can use it to [remove](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.12.4/dart-core/List/remove.html) from your List.

Comment: _players is the problem , in every selection of a player , the code above will be called again , which means _players list will recharge data from internet and will not see if the player is in selectedPlayers List or not , here is my problem , do you answer solve this problem?

Comment: Glad you found the problem