# Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0 Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

i am beginner in Flutter , i created a flutter application to display some data that come from internet, i had an error that says `RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0`
for few second and then this error dispappear after this.

Here what i have tried:

```
 import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:footyappp/Key/Key.dart';
    import 'package:footyappp/stats/player_goals.dart';
    import 'package:footyappp/stats/teams_json.dart';
    import 'package:footyappp/tables%20copy/league_board.dart';
    import 'package:footyappp/stats/player_assists.dart';
    import 'package:footyappp/stats/player_red_cards.dart';
    import 'package:footyappp/stats/player_yellow_cards.dart';
    import 'dart:convert';
    import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
    import 'assist_json.dart';
    import 'goals_json.dart';
    
    
    
    class Statss extends StatefulWidget {
    
    
      @override
      _StatssState createState() => _StatssState();
    }
    
    class _StatssState extends State<Statss> {
    
      List<AssistsJson> topassists = [];
      List<GoalsJson> topgoals = [];
      List<TeamsJson> teams = [];
      List<String> data = [];
      List<Choices> menu = [];
      String assister;
      String assisterphoto;
      String scorerphoto;
      String assists;
      String goals;
      String scorer;
      String teamgoals;
      String teamname;
      String teamphoto;
      String teampoints;
    
    
      Future<void>  getScorers() async {
        http.Response response = await http.get(
            'https://v3.football.api-sports.io/players/topscorers?league=39&season=2020',
            headers: {'x-rapidapi-key': ApiKey.key,
              'x-rapidapi-host':'v3.football.api-sports.io'});
        String body = response.body;
        var data = jsonDecode(body);
        List<dynamic> clubList = data['response'];
    
        setState(() {
          topgoals = clubList
              .map((dynamic item) => GoalsJson.fromJson(item))
              .toList();
          goals = topgoals[0].statistics[0].goals.total.toString();
          scorer = topgoals[0].player.name+" "+topgoals[0].player.firstname;
          scorerphoto = topgoals[0].player.photo;
        });
    
      }
    
      Future<void>  getStandings() async {
        http.Response response = await http.get(
            'https://v3.football.api-sports.io/standings?league=39&season=2020',
            headers: {'x-rapidapi-key': ApiKey.key,
              'x-rapidapi-host':'v3.football.api-sports.io'});
        String body = response.body;
        var data = jsonDecode(body);
        List<dynamic> clubList = data['response'];
    
        setState(() {
          teams = clubList
              .map((dynamic item) => TeamsJson.fromJson(item))
              .toList();
          teamgoals = teams[0].league.standings[0][0].all.goals.goalsFor.toString()+" "+"Goals";
          teamname =  teams[0].league.standings[0][0].team.name.toString();
          teamphoto = teams[0].league.standings[0][0].team.logo.toString();
          teampoints = teams[0].league.standings[0][0].points.toString()+" "+"Pts";
    
        });
    
      }
    
      Future<void>  getAssisters() async {
        http.Response response = await http.get(
            'https://v3.football.api-sports.io/players/topassists?league=39&season=2020',
            headers: {'x-rapidapi-key': ApiKey.key,
              'x-rapidapi-host':'v3.football.api-sports.io'});
        String body = response.body;
        var data = jsonDecode(body);
        List<dynamic> clubList = data['response'];
    
        setState(() {
          topassists = clubList
              .map((dynamic item) => AssistsJson.fromJson(item))
              .toList();
          assists = topassists[0].statistics[0].goals.assists.toString();
          assister = topassists[0].player.name+" "+topassists[0].player.firstname;
          assisterphoto = topassists[0].player.photo;
    
        });
    
      }
    
      @override
      void initState() {
        super.initState();
        getScorers();
        getAssisters();
        getStandings();
      }
    
      List<String> images = [
        "Assets/tt.jpg",
        "Assets/qatarairways.jpg",
        "Assets/LOGO_Danao.jpg",
        "Assets/delice.jpg"
      ];
    
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    
        if(topgoals.isNotEmpty && topassists.isNotEmpty){     this.menu = [
          Choices("Top Scorer: ", goals.toString(), topgoals[0].player.name,topgoals[0].player.photo.toString()),
          Choices("Top Assister: ", assists.toString(), topassists[0].player.name,topassists[0].player.photo.toString()),
          Choices("Top Team Goals ", teamgoals.toString(), "",teamphoto.toString()),
          Choices("1 st Team ", teampoints.toString(), "",teamphoto.toString()),
        ];}
        return  teams.isEmpty || topassists.isEmpty || topgoals.isEmpty
            ? Container(
          color: Colors.white,
          child: Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(
              valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(
                Color(0xFFe70066),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        )
            : Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              title: Text("Stats"),
              backgroundColor: Colors.blue[300],
              elevation: 0.0,
            ),
            body: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  gradient: LinearGradient(
                      begin: Alignment.centerLeft,
                      end: Alignment.centerRight,
                      colors: [Colors.purple, Colors.blue])),
              child: ListView(
                children: [
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 20,
                  ),
                  Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 0, 0, 0),
                    child: Text(
                      "Statistiques",
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 25,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
                          color: Colors.white),
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 30,
                  ),
                  Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
                    child: GridView.builder(
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      itemCount: menu.length,
                      gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                          crossAxisCount: 2,
                          crossAxisSpacing: 1.0,
                          mainAxisSpacing: 1.0),
                      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                        return Card(
                          color: Colors.black,
                          elevation: 4.0,
                          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                          ),
                          child: Container(
                            //padding:  EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                            child:
                            Column(
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Container(
                                  padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(30, 10, 30, 10),
                                  height: 100,
                                  width: 100,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              shape: BoxShape.circle,
                              image: DecorationImage(
                                  image: NetworkImage(menu[index].image),
                                  fit: BoxFit.fill
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                                Container(
                                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(7.0),
                                  width: double.infinity,
                                  child:
                                      Center(
                                        child: Text(menu[index].title+" "+menu[index].name,style: TextStyle(
                                            fontSize: 15,
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
                                            color: Colors.white),),
                                      )
                                ),
                                Container(
                                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(7.0),
                                  width: double.infinity,
                                  child: Center(
                                    child:  Text(menu[index].record, style: TextStyle(
                                        fontSize: 25,
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
                                        color: Colors.white),),
                                  ),
                                ),
    
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
    
                  Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15, 30, 15, 0),
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 1,
                        ),
                        ButtonTheme(
                          minWidth: double.infinity,
                          height: 40,
                          child: RaisedButton(
                              child: Align(
                                child: Text(
                                  "Top Scorers",
                                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 17),
                                  textAlign: TextAlign.right,
                                ),
                                alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                              ),
                              onPressed: () {
                                Navigator.push(
                                  context,
                                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Scorers()),
                                );
                              },
                              color: Colors.grey.shade300,
                              textColor: Colors.black,
                              padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15, 8, 8, 8),
                              splashColor: Colors.green,
                              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                  borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(30.0))),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 1,
                        ),
                        ButtonTheme(
                          minWidth: double.infinity,
                          height: 40,
                          child: RaisedButton(
                              child: Align(
                                child: Text(
                                  "Top Assists",
                                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 17),
                                  textAlign: TextAlign.right,
                                ),
                                alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                              ),
                              onPressed: () {
                                Navigator.push(
                                  context,
                                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Assists()),
                                );
                              },
                              color: Colors.grey.shade300,
                              textColor: Colors.black,
                              padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15, 8, 8, 8),
                              splashColor: Colors.green,
                              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                  borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(30.0))),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 1,
                        ),
                        ButtonTheme(
                          minWidth: double.infinity,
                          height: 40,
                          child: RaisedButton(
                              child: Align(
                                child: Text(
                                  "Yellow Cards",
                                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 17),
                                  textAlign: TextAlign.right,
                                ),
                                alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                              ),
                              onPressed: () {
                                Navigator.push(
                                  context,
                                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => YellowCards()),
                                );
                              },
                              color: Colors.grey.shade300,
                              textColor: Colors.black,
                              padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15, 8, 8, 8),
                              splashColor: Colors.green,
                              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                  borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(30.0))),
                        ),
    
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 1,
                        ),
                        ButtonTheme(
                          minWidth: double.infinity,
                          height: 40,
                          child: RaisedButton(
                              child: Align(
                                child: Text(
                                  "Red Cards",
                                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 17),
                                  textAlign: TextAlign.right,
                                ),
                                alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                              ),
                              onPressed: () {
                                Navigator.push(
                                  context,
                                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => RedCards()),
                                );
                              },
                              color: Colors.grey.shade300,
                              textColor: Colors.black,
                              padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15, 8, 8, 8),
                              splashColor: Colors.green,
                              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                  borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(30.0))),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 1,
                        ),
                        ButtonTheme(
                          minWidth: double.infinity,
                          height: 40,
                          child: RaisedButton(
                              child: Align(
                                child: Text(
                                  "Team Stats",
                                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 17),
                                  textAlign: TextAlign.right,
                                ),
                                alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                              ),
                              onPressed: () {
                                Navigator.push(
                                  context,
                                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => LeagueBoard()),
                                );
                              },
                              color: Colors.grey.shade300,
                              textColor: Colors.black,
                              padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15, 8, 8, 8),
                              splashColor: Colors.green,
                              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                  borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(30.0))),
                        ),
    
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 30,
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
                      child: GridView.builder(
                        shrinkWrap: true,
                        itemCount: images.length,
                        gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                            crossAxisCount: 2,
                            crossAxisSpacing: 4.0,
                            mainAxisSpacing: 4.0),
                        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                          return Image.asset(images[index]);
                        },
                      ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 30,
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ));
      }
    }
    
    
    class Choices {
      String title;
      String record;
      String name;
      String image;
    
      Choices(this.title,this.record,this.name,this.image);
    
    }
```

[image]

I am trying to find the reason behind this error and to fix it.
Why this error shows up for few second and then disappears?
Any help will be so appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens transiently, because at that given moment, in the build method, you are asking it to look at index[0], which means you are telling Flutter that there is at least 1 item in this list. It returns an error, saying that there is no such valid index, and shows the red screen, until your future function finishes running, and calls `setState` and now there are actually items at that index and it's not an empty list.

To resolve this, you can always check if your list is empty or not before building the widgets that depend on it, like this:

```
myList.isEmpty ? CircularProgressIndicator() : WidgetThatDependsOnTheListNotBeingEMpty()
```

This is also causing you a problem:

```
List<Choices> menu = [
           Choices("Top Scorer: ", goals.toString(), topgoals[0].player.name,topgoals[0].player.photo.toString()),
           Choices("Top Assister: ", assists.toString(), topassists[0].player.name,topassists[0].player.photo.toString()),
           Choices("Top Team Goals ", teamgoals.toString(), "",teamphoto.toString()),
           Choices("1 st Team ", teampoints.toString(), "",teamphoto.toString()),
         ];
```

For the same reasons mentioned above, you can change it to this:

```
if(topgoals.isNotEmpty && topassists.isNotEmpty)    List<Choices> menu = [
           Choices("Top Scorer: ", goals.toString(), topgoals[0].player.name,topgoals[0].player.photo.toString()),
           Choices("Top Assister: ", assists.toString(), topassists[0].player.name,topassists[0].player.photo.toString()),
           Choices("Top Team Goals ", teamgoals.toString(), "",teamphoto.toString()),
           Choices("1 st Team ", teampoints.toString(), "",teamphoto.toString()),
         ];
```

Comment: myList.isEmpty ? CircularProgressIndicator() : WidgetThatDependsOnTheListNotBeingEMpty()    Where to put this??

Comment: Anywhere you want to build a widget, which depends on a list not being empty. This will prevent the error screen or your app from throwing an error. Because if this list is empty, it will build a loading spinner, and not the widget which depends on the list. you can use this anywhere, not just in this code. and `myList` here is an example name.

Comment: WidgetThatDependsOnTheListNotBeingEmpty() is not defined for type Statts State

Comment: Bro, are you serious? This is also a fake\example name, you replace this with your actual widget that is causing the problem!

Comment: ahhaha sorry , i am a real beginner in flutter , i will change this

Comment: I edited your post after the update, check now. TRy the code now, and see if the error still happens

Comment: 31:58: Error: A value of type 'Statss' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'bool'.
 - 'Statss' is from 'package:footyappp/stats/statss.dart' ('lib/stats/statss.dart').
        topgoals.isEmpty ? CircularProgressIndicator() : Statss()

Comment: I fixed it as well for you, check now. Youc ant use `Statss()` like that.

Comment: no error is shown but the gridview just disappeared , i updated my code

Comment: Debug it. This is not how stackoverflow works. Try to pinpoint what the error is, you will eventually find it. Also, every post should contain one question, we're at three so far.

Comment: i mean it disappeared after we added this code , it was appearing before it but with the error that i spoke about

Comment: i found the solution , the menu variable is already declared so i deleted the List<Menu> menu and replaced it by this.menu

Comment: there is bounty about another question in Flutter that i still did not find any answer , feel free if you want to see , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67316833/delete-objects-from-datasources-in-selectable-datatable/67453108#67453108  Thank you again for all your help

Comment: Thank you so much!! This helped me a lot. Sometimes, little mistakes are made and a simple response can solve everything. You are my hero